# Cannot read property 'lessThan' of undefined

Tags: google-earth-engine

```js
Map.addLayer(gilgit)
Map.centerObject(gilgit,10)

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")

var image = l8.filterBounds(gilgit)

          .filterDate('2020-01-01','2021-12-30')
          .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',1)
          .median()
          .clip(gilgit)

Map.addLayer(image,imageVisParam,'true_colour')

var training = water.merge(buildup).merge(vegetation).merge(bareland)

print(training)

var bands = ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7']

var trainImage = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({collection:training,
properties: ['class'],
scale: 30,})

print (trainImage)

var trainData = trainImage.randomColumn()

var trainset = trainData.filter(ee.filter.lessThan('random',0.8))

var testset = trainData.filter(ee.filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random',0.8))

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
  featrue: trainset,
  classProperty:'class',
  inputproperties:bands})
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is an example of a "Wall of code" post, which does not contain any problem statement, and conveys "I give up, *you* can debug my code for me." Please [Edit] this Question to explain, in words, what your problem is, or it my be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ee.filter` in `ee.filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random',0.8)` and `ee.filter.lessThan('random',0.8)` with `ee.Filter`. Take a look to the [`ee.Filter`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-filter) class documentation. And `ee.Filter.lessThan` doesn't exist I think you meant `ee.Filter.lt`, so replace it.

Comment: sir i do that but cant be read

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas, I fixed my answer, try the update.